# How to display PDFs fetched from S3 using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, pdf-generation, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I need to fetch a PDF file from s3.amazonaws.com and when I query it using Postman (or paste directly into the browser), it loads fine. However when I try to generate the file path for it (to pass to a viewer later), it didn't work:

```js
fetch(<S3URL>).then(res => res.blob()).then(blob => {

    // THIS STEP DOES NOT WORK
    let myBlob = new Blob(blob, {type: 'application/pdf'});

    // expect something like 'www.mysite.com/my-file.pdf'
    let PDFLink = window.URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
        
    return PDFLink;        
}
```

I'm using Autodesk's Forge PDF viewer and it works perfectly fine for local PDF files:

```js
let myPDFLink = 'public/my-file.pdf';

Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, () => {
  viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(document.getElementById('forgeViewer'));
  viewer.start();
 
  viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.PDF').then( () => {
        viewer.loadModel(myPDFLink, viewer); // <-- works fine here        
  });
});

// from https://github.com/wallabyway/offline-pdf-markup
```

So, how do I go from the S3 URL (e.g. `s3.amazonaws.com/com.autodesk.oss-persistent/0d/ff/c4/2dfd1860d1...`) to something the PDF viewer can understand (i.e. has `.pdf` extension in the URL)?

I know for JSON files I need to do `res.json()` to extract the JSON content, but for PDFs, what should I do with the `res` object?

Note: I don't have control over the S3 URL. Autodesk generates a temporary S3 link whenever I want to download documents from their BIM360 portal.

Comment: Why not get the url of the pdf and open use `window.open`?

Comment: @KaviHarjani What should I do with the `res` object in order to get the URL of the PDF? The S3 link doesn't end with `.pdf` (but if you open it in browser, it will load). And I can't use `window.open` because I need the file to be open by that specific PDF viewer (it has some extra functionalities in it e.g. markups)

Comment: Okay 2 ways I can think of 
1. if you've control over s3
Remove `Content-Disposition` entry from that file. and set `Content-Type=application/pdf` .

2. If you don't have control over s3
so another way i can think of is on click, download the s3 object and store it in your server, and then provide the link for it `let myPDFLink = server-location;`

Comment: You said you're able to query the PDF from S3 without problems when using Postman or pasting the URL into browser, is that correct? Is the PDF available through a public URL then? With the PDF extension in Forge Viewer you should be able to load public URLs into the viewer without any problems. Is that not working for you?

Comment: @PetrBroz No, the PDF is not available through a public URL (the link doesn't end with `.pdf`). I read your answer from the other question as well; I don't control the S3 source so can't have it generate a public URL for me. Also to clarify: when pasted into the browser, the S3 link downloads the file, NOT displaying it (which is what I want). Postman can display it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a lot of options and the only way I could display a PDF *fetched via API calls* is by using an object element:

```
<object data='<PDF link>' type='application/pdf'>
```

Converting the downloaded blob to base64 doesn't work. Putting the PDF link in an iframe doesn't work either (it still downloads instead of displaying). All the options I have read only work if the PDFs are part of the frontend application (i.e. local files, not something fetched from a remote server).